# Tabela do Mysql travada

Tags: mysql

Ao tentar consultar a tabela via phpmyadmin nao há retorno e fica travado. 
Nem tentando fazer uma query com o php ele da retorno.

Alguma sugestão para resolver?

Comment: Tenta `REPAIR TABLE sua_tabela`

Comment: Também nao responde, fica so esperando a requisição e nada.

Comment: Essa tabela possui muitos registros? Pode ser problemas com índices.

Comment: Ah, algo em torno de 70000, mas o pior é que nao consigo deletar ela e nem o banco de dados. Como se estive rodando algum processo ainda.

Comment: Problema de índice? - Pode ser... Tenta então `OPTIMIZE TABLE sua_tabela`

Comment: Bom, tabela travada pode ser resolvido com o restart do sem XAMP ou WAMP. Em casos mais extremos, reiniciei o computador e tente novamente. Analise também o índice dessa table

Comment: Tente usar o Mysql Workbench ou o console, talvez seja um problema no seu drive phpmysql.

Answer (score 2):

use `show full processlist;` para ver o processo que está travando a tabela em seguida use `kill [id_do_processo]`